# como faço pra chamar o método do controller dentro da view?

Tags: php

tenho esse método :

```
public function Menu()
{

    $tabelas = $this->menu->All();

    $menus ="<ul><li>";

    foreach ($tabelas as $tabela )
    {
        if ($tabela->active == !false)
        { 
          //  $return = $this->categoria->All();

            foreach ($tabela as $key => $value )
            {

                if($key->active == !false)
                {
                    $menus .="<li>{$key} <a href= ></a></li> ";
                }
            }   
        }

        $menus.= "</li></ul>";
    }
    return $menus ;
}
```

queria saber como faço para chamar ele na view , pra ver como ele ta retornando e montando as coisas ...

```
public function create()
{
    $this->setPageTitle('Menu');
    echo  $this->categoria->Menu(); die;
    $this->renderView('rotas/RouteMenus', 'layoutForm');
}
```

ta dando erro :Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Menu() on null

Comment: vc não deveria fazer isso.  Qual é o problema que acontece?

Comment: quero montar o meu menu dinamicamente dando um select na tabela do banco , ja testei meu select que é aquela chamada pro método all() ali ta trazendo de boa , e agora só queria dar uma chamada nesse método menu na view pra ver como ele ta montando a <ul> e tals

Comment: Guarde o retorno de `Menu()` em uma variável dê um echo para teste ou passe ele direto para view, depois dê um echo.

Comment: joguei um echo  dentro do método que renderiza pra view mais deu erro :Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Menu() on null

Comment: Pelo codigo da para supor algumas coisas. Ao chamar `$this->categoria->Menu()`, nessa ordem seria necessario que a propriedade `categoria` retornase uma instancia da classe onde foi criada a função `Menu()`. Pela descrição do erro apresentada da para perceber que `$this->categoria` retorna o valor `null`. Seria interessante indicar em que classes estão as funções mostradas.